# ClassUtils.getDefaultClassLoader().getResource("").getPath() the obtained result value contains '!'

Tags: java

When I want to use `ClassUtils.getDefaultClassLoader().getResource("").getPath()` to get the file path, it returns `*.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/*`. But actually the file path does not contain **!**. It just looks like `*.jar/BOOT-INF/classes/*`.

I want to know why and how to deal with this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking for a blank resource, that's not a good idea. Ask for an actual, real resource. And, generally, don't ask the 'default class loader', because you have no idea what that might be, ask for the loader of a class you know. For example:

```
public class Example {
    void foo() {
        URL resource = Example.class.getResource("Example.class");
    }
}
```

This is a class, asking where its own class file is; works in all cases, even exotic ones, such as when we're in an agent environment.

Secondarily, the point of 'classpath resources' is that they are things provided by a class loader. The ClassLoader is an API (as in, anybody can write an implementation; it's like an interface), which demands that you provide the following tooling:

1. Given the name of a resource, you must be able to return all matching entries, in both 'URL' form, as well as in InputStream form.

That's it. There is #2. In particular, there is no need to serve anything sensible when asking for a blank resource, it is not possible to ask a classloader to list all resources it can serve, and **the resources it serves do not have to be files**.

In fact, usually, they aren't.

In this case, the resource you are getting is for some entry in a jar file, which isn't a file, and thus, isn't a Path, and thus, calling .getPath() on it, is nonsensical, and returns useless garbage.

The solution is to realize that it is impossible to turn a general resource into a path.

So, let's take a step back: You had some unstated problem X and thought: I know! I'll ask for the blank resource, turn that into a path, and that solves my problem! - but now you have questions about that. But the problem is, that was not the right solution to whatever X is.

The reason you're getting an ! is because the URL for a resource inside a jar file looks like:

```
jar:file://absolute/path/to/jarfile.jar!/entryname/in/jar.class
```

for example. The ! separates 'path to the jar' from 'path of the resource inside the jar'. There is no way to turn any of this straight into a `java.io.File` or `java.nio.file.Path` instance because... entries in jar files aren't themselves files.